# Proxmox Networking configuration with multiple VM

Tags: debian, routing, proxmox, hetzner

I have purchased a dedicated server from Hetzner and it comes with a single IP address. I installed Proxmox and now this IP is used to access the web portal.

I got another IP address for a VM on this node.

I cannot configure other VMs to access internet by any means.

What I need is, VM with public IP and all other VMs can access the internet (such as Windows VM)

How can I do this?

Thanks all

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work? Show the traces of what you already did so we can help you solve the problem at hand. Also clarify what your question which is rather vague in its current state.

Comment: Hello 
i tried to make vmbr0 bridging the NIC using the ip of the dedicated server then use the virtual mac while creating the new VM and i was able to access the public VM, but rest of VMs cannot access the internet

Comment: second solution i made vmbr0 and vmbr1 but the server keeps crashing

Comment: so what i can tell is either setup the whole proxmox to use NAT , where all VMs must have IP and gateway like 10.0.0.2 etc.. or just make one public VM using my second ip and MAC address, i cannot achieve both,

Comment: that what i want to achieve 
https://i.imgur.com/7kblW67.jpeg

Comment: Please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1113608/edit) your post and add these information there, instead of creating all these comments.